# Scraping PDFs from page containing multiple search results

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am interested in scraping PDFs from any of the speakers on this page. How might I go about this: https://www.nas.gov.sg/archivesonline/speeches/search-result?search-type=advanced&speaker=Amy+Khor

The website has changed from previous occasions and the code used previously such as this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.nas.gov.sg/archivesonline/speeches/search-result?search-type=advanced&speaker='

search_term = 'Amy+Khor'

data = {
    'keywords': search_term,
    'search-type': 'basic',
    'keywords-type': 'all',
    'page-num': 1
}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.post(url, data=data).text, 'lxml')

cnt = 1
while True:

    print()
    print('Page no. {}'.format(cnt))
    print('-' * 80)

    for a in soup.select('a[href$=".pdf"]'):
        print(a['href'])

    if soup.select_one('span.next-10'):
        data['page-num'] += 10
        cnt += 1
        soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.post(url, data=data).text, 'lxml')
    else:
        break
```

The code above no longer works...

Comment: What information are you looking for? The content of the pdf files, or the urls of those files?

Comment: I'll like to obtain the pdfs.

Comment: Again: do you want the actual *content* from those pdf's, or the urls of those pdfs?

Comment: Meant to download the PDFs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all PDF links from the pages you can use next example:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.nas.gov.sg/archivesonline/speeches/search-result"

params = {
    "search-type": "advanced",
    "speaker": "Amy Khor",
    "page-num": "1",
}

for params["page-num"] in range(1, 3):    # <--- increase number of pages here
    soup = BeautifulSoup(
        requests.get(url, params=params).content, "html.parser"
    )
    for a in soup.select('a[href$="pdf"]'):
        print("https:" + a["href"])
    print("-" * 80)
```

Prints:

```
https://www.nas.gov.sg/archivesonline/data/pdfdoc/MINDEF_20171123001_2.pdf
https://www.nas.gov.sg/archivesonline/data/pdfdoc/MSE_20151126001.pdf
https://www.nas.gov.sg/archivesonline/data/pdfdoc/MSE_20160229002.pdf

...and so on.
```

Comment: Thanks for this! It works! The last step is incomplete though, but it's ok - I can download the PDFs with the url.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it if I were to start from scratch.

Google Search is actually pretty powerful, and I feel like this query gets your pdfs:

> "Amy Khor" site:https://www.nas.gov.sg/archivesonline/data/pdfdoc filetype:pdf

Then, I'd use either BeautifulSoup or, even better, something like [googlesearch-python](https://pypi.org/project/googlesearch-python/) to get the results and process them into your desired lxml format.

Comment: If you have a sample code and some results, that would be great. I tried the googlesearch-python approach and it's less than ideal - I got a "Too many requests" error. Thanks for the approaches!